# Is there any way I can get a program that relies on Java7 and JavaFX2 to run "portably"?

Tags: java, javafx-2, portability

I'm writing a program with Java7 and JavaFX2, but I'll need to show it to people who only have access to machines with Java 6 installed (with no JavaFX).

Is there any way I can find a solution to this short of asking them to install Java7 and JavaFX2?

Comment: Develop in Java 6, then. If that doesn't work for you, it won't work for anyone else, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically yes, but you have to check if that is conform to the license conditions of Sun/Oracle the owner of JavaFX:

You could sue tools like http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/
They pack all your java  into one jar.

Another possibility you could obfuscate your application and include JavaFX.
But this, too might violate the license conditions.

Both solutions might be more work, than the effort off installing JavaFX to the (one)clients computer.

Try JavaFX2 for JavaSE6

On page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html
Download Download JavaFX 2.2.3 for Java SE 6 ...

Comment: How will a program compiled in Java 7 run under Java 6 (based on your answer)?

Comment: Class file compatibility is a minor issue compared to the differences in the JDK library. There is not much chance that JavaFX2, specifically developed against Java 7, will work on 6.

Comment: So if I package it into one JAR does that mean they wouldn't have to worry about having JavaFX2 installed, but would have to worry about Java6 vs. Java7? :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can create a self-contained application package by "bundling" your program with Java 7 and JavaFX 2.  That way you don't have to worry about what's on or not on your user's machine.
You can read more about self-contained application packaging at http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse JDT, you can configure your projects "Java Compiler", by "Enable project specific settings", to "Compiler compliance level" value 1.6. This should produce bytecode in a version suitable for Java 1.6 VM. I suppose, but am not sure, that Eclipse shall also warn you if you use library elements not present in the 1.6 library version; though you can be careful about that with or without warnings. As with the previous solutions, JavaFX you can just package in your application's JAR if the license agreement allows it.